# env file not loaded by NextJS

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm trying to load an env variable with NextJS version 9.5.

I've created a file named `.env.production` at the root of my project following the official NextJS documentation over here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables

Here's my env file content:

```
# APP VARIABLES
# ...

# Webservices
NEXT_PUBLIC_WEBSERVICE_HOST=$WEBSERVICE_HOST

# Keycloak
NEXT_PUBLIC_KEYCLOAK_HOST=$KEYCLOAK_HOST
NEXT_PUBLIC_KEYCLOAK_REALM=$KEYCLOAK_REALM
NEXT_PUBLIC_KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID=$KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID
```

I need these variables to be available on the browser as well so I've prepended the env variable name with `NEXT_PUBLIC_`.

Once I launch the app, I can see that the env file are loaded correctly:

```
> project@ start /app
> NODE_ENV=production node dist/server/server.js
info  - Loaded env from /app/.env.production
> Config - API host: https://<redacted>
> Config - Keycloak host: https://<redacted>
> Ready on localhost:3000 - env production
```

But once in the browser when I try to call the API using this piece of code

```
const keycloakUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_KEYCLOAK_HOST as string
const keycloakRealm = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_KEYCLOAK_REALM as string
export const clientId = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID as string

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: `${keycloakUrl}/auth/realms/${keycloakRealm}`,
  timeout: 30000,
})

# ...

instance.post('/').catch(console.err);
```

I can see that my variables `keycloakUrl` and `keycloakRealm` are empty when I call my API.

How can I solve this problem ?